# Visual Studio 2013 C++ link static library glew, glfw on virtual machine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, glfw, glew

I can't link static libraries in my visual studio 2013 c++ project.

1. I downloaded latest glew-1.11.0-win32 and glfw-3.1.1.bin.WIN32
2. Set path to include directory 
   (project Properties > C/C++ "Additional Include Directories")

   ```
   C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OpenGL\OpenGL\Common
   ```
3. Add path to lib files
   (project Properties > Linker > General "Additional Library Directories")

   ```
   C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OpenGL\OpenGL\Common\Libs
   ```
4. Add library names
   (project Properties > Linker > Input "Additional Dependencies")

   ```
   glew32.lib
   glfw3.lib
   ```
5. Define preprocesor GLEW_STATIC (it's visible when I remove this)

   ```
   (project Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor "Preprocessor Definitions")
   ```

When I build my project following error occur:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _glewExperimental C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenGL\OpenGL\Source.obj    OpenGL
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenGL\Debug\OpenGL.exe OpenGL
```

When I want to comple this

```
#include<Windows.h>


#include<GL\glew.h>
#include<GLFW\glfw3.h>

#include<iostream>

GLFWwindow * window;

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    glewExperimental = TRUE;
    GLenum error = glewInit();
    if (error != GLEW_OK)
    {
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Windows 8.1 on virutal machine(VirtualBox) and Mirosoft Visual Studio 2013

What I am doing wrong? In other topics on this forum this solution works properly.

When I remove this two libs from directories I got same error, so probably Visual don't see these two libs. But path is set properly. Include path works, all header files are visible by intelsense.

Comment: Looking at [the docs here](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html), it seems to me that `glew32.lib` is not the actual static lib, but rather just an import lib for `glew32.dll`. The document seems to imply that you need to actually build the lib alongside your sources in order to link statically to it.

Comment: Do You know how to do that? Every tutorial is about linking own dll library. I found this one [link](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/2012/03/how-to-consume-dlls-in-visual-cxx/comment-page-1/) but it did not work. Any idea?

Comment: I downloaded the binary package from the GLEW site and found that, in the `lib\Release\Win32` directory, alongside `glew32.lib`, there's also `glew32s.lib`. I have a sneaking suspicion that the one with the `s` is the actual static lib you're looking for. So, make only this change in `Additional Dependencies` and try again (everything else seems fine in your setup, and the document I referenced in the previous comment seems to be out of date - [this other page](http://glew.sourceforge.net/build.html) says that a pre-built static lib should be included in the binary Windows package).

Answer (score 2):

@bogdan is correct: the static library version of GLEW is **glew32s.lib**.

BTW, the [GLEW installation page](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html) on sourceforge.net says you have to "include include glew.h and glew.c into your project if you want static linking." While that sounds easy enough, it seemed like unnecessary roughness to do it for every openGL project.  Instead, do the following:

- Add the **GLEW_STATIC** Macro under *Properties - Common Properties - 
  C/C++ -  Preprocessor - Preprocessor Definitions*
- Add **glew32s.lib** under *Properties - Common Properties - Linker - Input - Additional Library Dependencies*
- If you didn't copy glew32s.lib to one of Visual Studio's default library paths, add the path to it under under *Properties - Common Properties - Linker - General - Additional Library Directories*

Worked for me.

In case you aren't aware of this, you can **Add New Property Sheet**, e.g. *openglPropertySheet32Static*, in the **Property Manager** (*View menu - Other Windows - Property Manager*).  Add your openGL specific properties to it. Don't forget to explicitly save the sheet--I'm not sure it is saved automatically with the project. Then, all you have to do for future openGL projects is **Add Existing Property Sheet**, *openglPropertySheet32Static*, in the Property manager (you remember where you saved it, right?).

Comment: Beautiful. After hours of searching for a solution to my stupid DLL problems.